# Web interface running ipython shell

Tags: python, ipython, html

Is there a framework i can use or something already in place to get a ipython loaded or embed into a webpage. Something similar similar to [this](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/). The ipython shell will need to be loaded from a virtualenv.

Comment: If you need a good example of someone doing it, DataCamp.com does a great job of integrating IPython into their web site. Best I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can use something like http://liftoff.github.io/GateOne/About/ to give you a 'real' tty via a webpage and run python in that, but.. huge security hole.

Alternatively you could try porting ipython into http://repl.it/languages/Python which may or may not be do-able.. It'll probably be a huge amount of effort if you're not well versed in both python, unix/posix and javascript. And even if you are, if you provide any real python backend thruogh the web server, it'll be a huge security hole (i.e. system('/usr/bin/command'), even if running as a web only / daemon user.

There are a couple 'full python interpreter in javascript' projects that use enscripten (like repl.it), if you can make do with that you're probably golden.